# Why is the following fs.writeFile only writing data from the last file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read the content of two files (same folder) and write them into a single one:

```
  const input = process.argv[2]

  fs.readdir(__dirname + `/${input}/`, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return
    }

    files.forEach((file) => {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + `/${input}/` + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        let items = []
        items.unshift(data)
        let result = items.join('\n\n')

        fs.writeFile("untitled2.html", result, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log(result)
          }
        })
      })
    })
  })
```

`console.log(result)` outputs the content of the two files:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2n/bin$ node index4.js folder

File 1

File 2
```

The file, however, has only the content from the second file:

```
File 2
```

What's happening here?

Comment: The `ecmascript-6` tag is specifically for question about new features of ES6. Don't use it if you are merely using ES6 but the question is about something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `writeFile` but [`appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback) when your goal is to append to a file without replacing the content (`appendFile` takes care of creating the file when necessary).

You're also not waiting for the appending to be finished, which might lead to errors. You have various solutions here:

- promises
- a recursive function handling files one after the other
- use `appendFileSync` (assuming you're writing an utility rather than a server)

Exemple with the recursive function:

```
(function doOneFile(){
    var file = files.shift();
    if (!file) return;
    fs.readFile(__dirname + `/${input}/` + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        let items = []
        items.unshift(data)
        let result = items.join('\n\n')

        fs.appendFile("untitled2.html", result, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log(result)
          }
          doOneFile();
        })
    })
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the default options, `writeFile` erases previous contents every time. It's the "write mode". What you want is switch to "append mode", like so :

```
fs.writeFile("untitled2.html", result, {flag:"a"}, callbacks...);
```

In the process, you'll need to take care to erase the possible file contents before your loop, or have the first access be in write mode. Otherwise you'll keep appending to previsously existing contents.

Besides, in this case you'll be hitting problems with concurrent accesses. Either use the synchronous forms, or loop through files via a callback.